# BJT transistor *physical* structure

Tags: bjt

I have come across an image that shows image of cross section of an actual transistor. I have always seen conceptual diagrams so far but this is a real transistor structure. This diagram has totally confused me.

[image]

There are a lot of questions that arise. I would be grateful if someone could answer a few, or guide me to a resource that explains the *actual physical structure* in detail.

1. Why is there a p+-substrate? Shouldn't the base be undopped silicon? And Why p+ and not normal p?
2. What is that p+ with sustrate contact on the right?
3. Why is n+ burried layer required?
4. A tiny little emitter and collector taking most area is quite surprising. Shouldn't this cause big resistance in the current path since emitter is so tiny compared with collector? Why not make the emitter area bigger?

Comment: quantum231 - Hi, Please can you name & link to (or otherwise [reference](/help/referencing) as explained in the link) the source of that image? Thanks.

Comment: That is a transistor as implemented on an integrated circuit with other transistors. Most of your questions relate to structures required to keep such transistors electrically isolated from each other. A discrete transistor is much simpler than this.

Comment: quantum231 : (1) Power supply conventions and lower carrier mobility in p+. (2) To provide contact (if needed) to the substrate. (3) To reduce collector resistance. (4) Collector is where most of the heat is generated. (There are other reasons.)

Comment: quantum231 : Get a book that provides a good overview. Books on this topic will usually have the two words **SOLID STATE** in their title. One I've liked is *"Solid State Electronic Devices"*, 7th edition, Ben Streetman and Sanjay Banerjee. You'll enjoy chapter 7, I think, section 7.3 in particular.

Comment: how does higher doping (marked with + sign) lead to a better contact at the terminals? Better means lower resistance or something else?

Comment: @quantum231 Lower resistance, but also if the doping is too low you're more likely to form a Schottky junction than an ohmic contact, and that would render your transistor useless.

Comment: @quantum231 Your substrate (pictured with about the thickness of a 2" wafer in your diagram) is usually p-type as it leads to fewer steps (cheaper.) It also doesn't show the self-aligned double poly process, which would have SiO2 (LOCOS) isolation showing. In any case, the buried layer helped a lot because the collector contacts are at the top (as you can see) and this increases the overall collector bulk resistance. To reduce the collector resistance, the buried layer is added with a heavily doped mashed in between the N-epi and the P-substrate. It provides a low resistance *shunt* path.

Comment: @quantum231 But you also don't seem to realize that the conductivity is improved by doping. You should realize that fact. It's kind of obvious. But your *"how does higher doping lead to ..."* suggests to me that you do not realize this fact. So perhaps that's why you can't recognize the advantage offered by the buried layer. Regardless of what you can recognize, the fact is that the buried layer reduces the collector's resistance as seen from the topside metalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many (!) transistors are made in layers by depositing over an insulating substrate of silicon . The [epiwafer](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Epitaxial_wafer) is cut and polished from a large cylinder of pure [monocrystal silicon](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Monocrystaline_silicon).

Each layer like a multilayer printed circuit board is applied with photomasks so that the next process can etch features with a laser , then the mask is dissolve and the next layer is masked, deposited, etched, dissolved, rinsed then then repeated. Each layer is made from different materials of either semiconductors between metallic electrodes added to leads, pads or balls then encapsulated.

Each region is [doped](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Doping_(semiconductor)) with fuming hot pressurized chemicals in each layer to make n or p-type materials with various concentrations and depths.

**[The p-n junction is created by doping](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/P%E2%80%93n_junction)**, for example by ion implantation, diffusion of dopants, or by epitaxy (growing a layer of crystal doped with one type of dopant on top of a layer of crystal doped with another type of dopant).

If two separate pieces of material were used, this would introduce a grain boundary between the semiconductors that would severely inhibit its utility by scattering the electrons and holes.  [*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/P%E2%80%93n_junction)

Not to be confused with the popular N-type [MG converti](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/n-type?fullSearch=true)ble.
[image]

The process of explaining this starts from a 1D to a 2D to the real 3D process but they are real 3D parts shown by symbolic logic diagrams so that you learn to associate the logic with the bipolar or analog characteristics of the basic NPN or PNP  [BJT.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bipolar_junction_transistor)

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-2/bipolar-junction-transistors/

https://www.slideserve.com/daniel_millan/bipolar-junction-transistors-bjt-powerpoint-ppt-presentation

Comment: (Why hyperlink to wikiwand instead of [en.wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor)?)

Comment: WHy not? it looks better.  Wikiwand is a leading donor to the Wikimedia Foundation,  My answer , my choice.